# Real Zeros - tail estimate

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, polynomials

Given a random polynomial with Gaussian coefficients, the Kac-Rice formula tells us what the expected number of real zeros is (for more on this, see the excellent paper of Edelman and Kostlan in the Bulletin of the AMS, 1995). What I am interested in, however, is any sort of a tail estimate: what is the probability that the random polynomial of degree $N$ has at least $m$ real zeros (in the original Kac case, since the expectation is logarithmic in $N,$ I assume that this should decay exponentially in $m.$

Comment: This is a well known open question...  A partial info: if $m=\alpha N$ then I believe that the probability is actually exponential in $N^2$ (one can write a LDP for the empirical measure of zeros, from which this will follow).  So the interesting regime for your question is  when $m=o(N)$ (but $\log N=o(m)$). I think one can push the LDP analysis to $m=N^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ close to $1$, but not for all $\alpha$.

Comment: @oferzeitouni Do you have a reference for the gaussian tail? After posting the question, I found that Hough-Krishnapur-Peres-Virag talk about it, but I think they only get an exponential decay (in some regime). Thanks!

Comment: With Gaussian COMPLEX coefficients, the LDP for the empirical measure  is done in a paper of Zelditch and myself: http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4271 . (The LDP bound gives that the empirical measure can't give too much weight to a neighborhood of the rel line). The technique in that paper for Kac polynomials goes over also to the real coefficients case (for the same question for random matrices with real iid Gaussian entries, this was done earlier by Ben Arous and myself).